# How to display "Times new roman" font for Romanian language in pdf using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, stylesheet, html-to-pdf

LoadTagStyle does not work for tag body with times new roman font
I want to generate in pdf document one html page inside his I have font times new roman
I try to set font times new roman but his not work

I tried several cases:

```
 var styles = new StyleSheet();

1. styles.LoadTagStyle("body", "font-family", "times new roman");
2. styles.LoadTagStyle("body", "face", "times new roman");
3. styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, "face", "times new roman");
4. styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.FONT, "times new roman");
```

but none of these examples work

Also I tried :

```
FontFactory.RegisterDirectories();
```

and

```
FontFactory.Register(FULL_PATH_TO_TIMES_NEW_ROMAN);
```

and

```
style.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.TABLE, HtmlTags.FACE, "times-roman");
```

generated text is without diacritics
some proposal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solve my problem

```
            FontFactory.Register("c:\\windows\\fonts\\times.ttf");
            StyleSheet st = new StyleSheet();
            st.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.TABLE, "border", "1");
            st.LoadTagStyle("body", "face", "times new roman");
            st.LoadTagStyle("body", "encoding", "Identity-H");
```

Answer (score -1):

**I tried this Itz Working 
Jst Try It.**

---

```
 FontFactory.RegisterDirectories();

 styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.TABLE, HtmlTags.FONT, "comic-sans-ms");
```